Is it damaging to have a Withdraw on a continuing education transcript when applying to PhD program?
Currently I am taking a fairly relevant course (self-paced, online) from a continuing education (CE) service of a U.S. regional institution. Today, I am planning to drop it because:

I was also taking another course (term-based) and I work a full-time job. It has been hard to handle the courses for me, and I might not make it before the deadline of the course,
I was taking the course to refresh my knowledge and thought that it would offer new knowledge, but after several modules, it looks like the course has a lot of overlap with one I took few years ago in college.

My question is, will a W be damaging to my application when it is the only thing on the transcript from this CE service? and how should I address/explain this if I need to?

For US admissions, at least, I wouldn't worry about it. A W isn't a failure. The explanations you give here are enough, but it seems unlikely you would even be asked.
If you had half a dozen withdrawals, it might raise questions, but would, again be unlikely to be disqualifying in most cases.
Admissions judgements are based on more important and relevant things.

Thank you, I was very worried because I would have a separate transcript with only a W on it. If I understand correctly, I won't have to explain it in my SoP?

Don't use the SoP to explain the past. Make it future looking. What are your goals for grad study and thereafter?

Thank you, I was using the SoP to mainly discuss my motivation, goal, and plan. It is reassuring that I don't need to explain a W

A few words about career goals can also help, IMO.

A graduate committee wants confidence that you won't flunk out on coursework and waste the resources the program has pumped into you.  A W will hurt if you have too many C's on the rest of your transcript.

Actually, too many C's is an issue even without any W. Especially in core courses. That would need serious explaining.

Thank you both! I actually did not get a C in undergraduate study so I guess I am safe
